# SQL Oracle: add column from other table twice but with reference to different tables

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables.
One of those tables has a key (unique Number) and out of this table I need a column ("Number-Text") to to be added twice in my output table.

Table1:

| BelNo | Plant | ProductNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | 999 |
| 234 | A | 888 |
| 345 | B | 989 |
| 456 | A | 999 |

Table2:

| BelNo | MaterialNo |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 001 |
| 234 | 002 |
| 345 | 001 |

Table3 (with unique values -> each "No" is unique / no duplicates):

| No | Number-Text |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Wood |
| 002 | Metal |
| 888 | Chair |
| 999 | Bed |

What I try to get is following table:

| BelNo | Plant | ProductNo | Number-Text | MaterialNo | Number-Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | 999 | Bed | 001 | Wood |
| 234 | A | 888 | Chair | 001 | Wood |
| 345 | B | 989 | Wardrobe | 002 | Metal |
| 456 | A | 999 | Bed | 001 | Wood |

My Problem is, that with my current code "Number-Text" shows in both columns always the Text from ProductNo ("Bed", "Chair", ...).
What needs to be done, to get a reference in the second "Number-Text" to the column "MaterialNo"?

Here is my current code:

```
SELECT

Table1.BelNo,
Table1.Plant,
Table1.ProductNo,
Table3.Number-Text,
Table2.MaterialNo,
Table3.Number-Text

FROM
Table1 

LEFT JOIN Table3  ON Table1.ProductNo = Table3.No AND Table3.Language = 'E'

LEFT JOIN Table2  ON Table1.BelNo =Table2.BelNo

WHERE
Table1.Plant = 'A'
```

Sorry, it is my first post. Hope the problem is clearly defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where table aliases come in.

To join on a table twice, you give at least the second occurrence an alias.  I tend to give both occurrences aliases...

```
SELECT
    Table1.BelNo,
    Table1.Plant,
    Table1.ProductNo,
    product.Number-Text   AS product_text,
    Table2.MaterialNo,
    material.Number-Text  AS material_text
FROM
    Table1 
LEFT JOIN
    Table3  product
        ON  product.No       = Table1.ProductNo
        AND product.Language = 'E'
LEFT JOIN
    Table2
        ON  Table2.BelNo = Table1.BelNo
LEFT JOIN
    Table3  material
        ON  material.No = Table2.MaterialNo
WHERE
    Table1.Plant = 'A'
```

Comment: @M123 That's an Oracle error message.  Oracle has different syntax constraints for table aliases *(it don't allow the `AS` keyword there)*.  Please edit your question to tag that it's Oracle?  I'll edit the answer.